# VBA Type mismatch(error 13) on inheritance, user from

Tags: excel, vba, inheritance

Environment
・Excel 2016
・Windows10

Issues
・Type mismatch

I am doing VBA practice and the task is to make UserForm, and input will be shown on the sheet.

Photo1, click "Portfolio" -> The Userform is shown(Photo2), then Choose Currency and pill the Quantity, ExchangeRate, buy/sell then Click "Add Transaction"

↓

Then, Error is shown witch is type mismatch 13. When I clicked the "Debug", the issue is the yellow line, but I am not sure how can I fix it.

The input shoud be shown on the Photo3 (Inside Sheet("TransactionHistory") from Date to Rate)

[image: Photo1]
[image: Photo2]
[image: Photo3]
[image: Photo4]
[image: Photo5]

↓UserForm Codes

```html
Private Sub btnAddtransaction_Click()
Dim newTransaction As New transaction

newTransaction.TransactionDate = Now()

If (optCredit) Then
newTransaction.transactionType = Credit
End If
If (optDebit) Then
newTransaction.transactionType = Debit
End If

save newTransaction
newTransaction.CryptCurrency = cmBoxCurrency.Value
newTransaction.Quantity = txtboxQuantity.Value
newTransaction.ExchangeRate = txtboxExchangerate.Value

End Sub
Public Sub save(transaction As transaction)
Dim validator As New TransactionValidator
If (validator.isValid(transaction)) Then
Worksheets("TransactionHistory").Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown

Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("A2") = transaction.TransactionDate

If (transaction.transactionType = Credit) Then
Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("B2") = "Credit"
Else
Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("B2") = "Debit"
End If

Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("C2") = transaction.CryptCurrency
Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("D2") = transaction.Quantity
Sheets("TransactionHistory").Range("E2") = transaction.ExchangeRate
End If

End Sub


Private Sub btnOk_Click()
```

↓Transaction

```html
Public CryptCurrency As String
 Public ExchangeRate As Double
 Public Quantity As Double
 Public TransactionDate As Date
 Public transactionType As transactionType
 
 Public Function tostring() As String
 tostring = CryptCurrency & " " & transcriptionType & " " & "quantity: " & Quantity & "rate: " & ExchangeRate
 End Function
```

```html
Public Function isValid(transaction As transaction) As Boolean

If (transaction Is Nothing) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.CryptCurrency <= 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.Quantity < 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.ExchangeRate < 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

End Function
```

↓TransactionValidator

```html
Public Function isValid(transaction As transaction) As Boolean

If (transaction Is Nothing) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.CryptCurrency <= 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.Quantity < 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

If (transaction.ExchangeRate < 0) Then
isValid = False
End If

End Function
```

Here is the task description figure
[image: Photo6]
[image: Photo7]

Comment: Side note: your boolean `isValid()` function doesn't return any `True` result, only `False` which btw is the function's default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running UserForm, when you click "Debug" the line highlighted is not necessarily one where the error occurs.
I suspect `If (transaction.CryptCurrency <= 0) Then` causes error as you campare a string with integer here.

Use `transaction.CryptCurrency <> ""` instead

Comment: I deleted that if statement and the error have been removed.
However, in that case, how can I check "not an empty string"?

Comment: transaction.CryptCurrency <> ""

Comment: When debugging in classes you need to make sure  Tools.Options.General.Error Trapping. Break on all errors is checked otherwise the highlighted line is the call into the class and not the error line in the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like part of the problem is that you are making objects with the same name as classes/modules. You shouldn't have "transaction as transaction" (object as class), but you could have "txn as transaction" or "transaction1 as transaction".

Otherwise how would the compiler or the reader know if you are referring to the class itself or the instance of the class?